# Ubuntu autoinstall disable prompt during iso installation

Tags: iso, cloud-init, user-data, autoinstall

I'm generating my own iso using autoinstall, here is the configuration:

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  identity:
    hostname: foo-ubuntu
    password: "qqqaaaqqqaaa"
    username: abcabc
  late-commands:
    - cp -r /cdrom/copy_to_iso/ /target/opt/
  user-data:
    runcmd:
      - |
        mkdir -vp /opt/INIT/
        mv -v /opt/copy_to_iso/upgrade_or_install_packages/ /opt/
        mv -v /opt/copy_to_iso/foo_installation/* /opt/INIT/ 
        mv -v /opt/copy_to_iso/appa_scripts /opt/appa_scripts
        rm -rvf /opt/copy_to_iso
        bash -x /opt/appa_scripts/setup_system_config.sh install_mode
```

In the part of the userdata during the installation, the user can use prompt and
I want prevent him from using prompt unless he presses ESC for example.
How can I do it? preferably without installing any packages.

Comment: Which part is causing the prompt? It it the script /opt/appa_scripts/setup_system_config.sh?

Comment: no, this part: setup_system_config.sh